# I can´t link Bootstrap 4.1.0 to my Laravel project

Tags: php, css, laravel

I´m trying to link bootstrap css to my Laravel proyect using

or  in my view but it not working.

In scss class I tried this:

```
  @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap' or @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

In view class I tried this:

```
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>-->
or <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('css/app.css')}}"/>
```

My scss class looks like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

@import 'variables';

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

//@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@import 'custom';
```

They show any errors, but it don´t load the bootstrap styles

Comment: Check the network tab of the developer console of your browser, and see what URL it's trying to load from and if it's the correct path from the `public` directory in your project.

Comment: Sass first needs to be compiled into css to work in browsers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll to go to your prompt and type

```
npm install bootstrap@4.1.0
```

Then, in your bootstrap.js file, inside the try statement, type this:

```
require ('bootstrap');
```

In your app.scss file

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Run:

```
npm run dev
```

In your view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your description, you only need to run npm dev

```
npm run dev
```

and add in any .blade.php file
in head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

in body tag:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```